# Systemctl failure using --global setting

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (using KDE desktop). I'm trying to set a systemd service to run globally using the

```
sudo systemctl --user --global enable *service*
```

command. It fails with

```
No such file or directory
```

However, when I execute

```
systemctl enable *service*
```

the command works with no errors.

What do I need to do to get the `--global` setting to work?

Comment: In which directory is your script located ?

Answer (score 0):

To make your service available for all user you have to put the script into the `/lib/systemd/user` directory.

It makes no sense to set `--user` and `--global` at the same time. Just run

```
sudo systemctl --global enable *service*
```

to enable the service globally.